# How do you restrict the number of rows in a <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given this code:

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

There are 4 rows to type.

However, how would you apply CSS to disable another row when a user presses enter or when the text overflows to the 5th row?

Answer (score 4):

To limit rows (lines) use [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). You will need to do this by the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/input_event) event,

and to split the lines in an array you can use the [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), after that the limit can be controlled with [`Array.prototype.slice(start, end)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), being `start` must have the `0`, which will be the first line obtained, and `end` being the maximum number of lines desired. Finally, we concatenate the array into a *string*.

See example:

> Note that I used `setTimeout` to avoid multiple executions in case the user holds any key interruptly.

```js
function limitText(textarea, limit) {
    function limitLines() {
        // split lines
        var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");

        if (lines.length > limit) {
            textarea.value = lines.slice(0, limit).join("\n");
        }
    }

    // Limite on add event
    limitLines();

    var timeout;

    textarea.addEventListener("input", function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(limitLines, 1);
    });
}

limitText(document.getElementById("txtField1"), 4);
limitText(document.getElementById("txtField2"), 4);
```

```html
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtField1">1
2
3
4</textarea>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="txtField2">a
b
c
d</textarea>
```

Comment: Your logic is not enough, it still expands row if you do copy and paste.

Comment: @DFXNguyễn You are right, it seems that if you paste the first line twice (or more) each time you paste it adds the limit line, I will try to revise it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, btw if you keep writing text without `Enter`press, it'll break line and get over max-rows .

Comment: Another note: If you have filled all the rows with content and then you press `Enter` on the first rows, the content of the last row will be deleted.

Comment: @NissimElbaz I think it's something I can improve in the script, I'll adjust it so that instead of just deleting nothing happens, using `event.preventDefault()`. Do you agree?

Comment: @Korvo I used your answer but in a different way, I used the `"onkeydown"` event, then I checked how many `"/n"` were exists, with `var lines = textarea.value.split("\n");`, and then I used this code: `if (lines.length > 4 && event.key === "Enter") { event.preventDefault(); }`.  But as they wrote here, it does not solve the problem of writing text without `Enter`

Answer (score 2):

### Using a textarea

Too limit rows and characters in a textarea you can use my script I just made:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function textarealimit(textarea, rows, chars, rowsleft_id, charsleft_id) {
    var newValue;
    var valueSegments = textarea.value.split('\n');
    if(rows != undefined && valueSegments.length > rows) { // too many rows
        newValue = valueSegments.slice(0, rows).join("\n");
    }
    if(chars != undefined && textarea.value.length > chars) { // too many chars
        if(newValue != undefined) 
            newValue = newValue.substring(0, chars);
        else
            newValue = textarea.value.substring(0, chars);
    }
    if(newValue != undefined) textarea.value = newValue;

    if(rowsleft_id != undefined) {
        if(textarea.value == "") document.getElementById(rowsleft_id).innerHTML = rows;
        else if(rows - valueSegments.length >= 0) document.getElementById(rowsleft_id).innerHTML = rows - valueSegments.length;
    }
    if(charsleft_id != undefined) {
        if(chars != undefined) document.getElementById(charsleft_id).innerHTML = chars - textarea.value.length;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea onkeydown="textarealimit(this, 4, 43, 'textarea_rowsleft', 'textarea_charsleft');" 
onkeyup="textarealimit(this, 4, 43, 'textarea_rowsleft', 'textarea_charsleft');" 
onpaste="textarealimit(this, 4, 43, 'textarea_rowsleft', 'textarea_charsleft');" 
rows="4" style="overflow: hidden; resize: none;">
</textarea>
<div>
    Rows left: <span id="textarea_rowsleft">4</span>
    Characters left: <span id="textarea_charsleft">43</span>
</div>
```

If you use HTML5 you can even limit the characters by the `maxlength` attribute on the textarea control.
If you do not want to show the rows or chars left, just use `onkey....="textarealimit(this, 4, 43);"`. You can even only limit the rows by using `onkey....="textarealimit(this, 4);"`.

Here is a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/AmFnA/9/

The only limitation appears when the user gets new rows by auto line breaks due to the width limitation, so without pressing ENTER, because it will NOT count as new row. Also, you have to use keydown (when the user presses and holds this fires all the time), keyup (when the user releases, fires even when pressing ENTER) and onpaste (for richtclick -> paste), always.

Thanks to Guilherme for reminding me on the paste part with his shorter version of that solution.

---

### Using multiple input fields

Now there is another alternative Jukka mentioned. You can use an input field for each row. This will prevent the user to get line breaks automatically. Here you can even listen up the keys to send the cursor to the next or previous box on the right conditions.

Build up your rows with input fields in your HTML:

```
<div class="rowfield_collection">
    <input id="rowfield1" class="rowfield top" onkeydown="rowfieldkeynav(event, undefined, 'rowfield2');" type="text" size="35" maxlength="30" />
    <input id="rowfield2" class="rowfield middle" onkeydown="rowfieldkeynav(event, 'rowfield1', 'rowfield3');" type="text" size="35" maxlength="30" />
    <input id="rowfield3" class="rowfield middle" onkeydown="rowfieldkeynav(event, 'rowfield2', 'rowfield4');" type="text" size="35" maxlength="30" />
    <input id="rowfield4" class="rowfield bottom" onkeydown="rowfieldkeynav(event, 'rowfield3', undefined);" type="text" size="35" maxlength="30" />
</div>
```

As you see, every input field got its own ID and you refer previous and next input field in the rowfieldkeynav call.

To style it and look it like a textarea you can use this CSS:

```
.rowfield {
    margin: 0 0 -1px 0;
    display: block;
}
.rowfield.top {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.rowfield.middle {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.rowfield.bottom {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

And finally the JAVASCRIPT function:

```
function rowfieldkeynav(e, before_id, after_id) {
    var evtobj = window.event ? event : e //distinguish between IE's explicit event object (window.event) and Firefox's implicit.
    var unicode = evtobj.charCode ? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode;
    if(before_id != undefined && e.currentTarget.value.length == 0 && unicode == 08) { // BACKSPACE
        document.getElementById(before_id).focus();
    }
    else if(after_id != undefined && unicode == 13 || e.currentTarget.value.length >= e.currentTarget.maxLength) { // ENTER or end of row reached
        document.getElementById(after_id).focus();
    }
}
```

It will jump to the previous input field when the current input field is empty and you press BACKSPACE. It will jump to the next input field when you press ENTER or reach the maxlength length.

And again, here a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/6KVMS/2/

The only few downsides on this method are:

- It will jump into a new line in the middle of a word, so it will not take the current word with you into the new input field.
- You cannot select more than one row when using your mouse.
- You can jump in the next rows by clicking there
- If you remove a row above another filled row, the text will not go up
- IE8 and perhabs lower cries a bit: It will not skip to the next field when the row is full

Comment: Just to be clear, I added the first answer on ROWS (it was a question of OP) on "Jul 20 at 0:12" and you just added (edit your question) on ROWS on "Jul 20 at 11:18".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento So what? When I came back from fiddle finishing this I did not mention another person did something similar like the first part of my answer now. Should I not correct my solutions with my own creations to help the OP, just because another person did something similar?

Comment: If another user posts a more correct answer that I realize I give my support to this user commenting on my own response and commenting on it or answer (usually give a upvote), this is to be a community, that is to have chivalry.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento I fully agree with you, unless I did not read your answer before. So I don't think it would be appropriate of myself for doing that. But, you handled the paste part and yours is shorter. I will correct my answer with the paste part and take the chivalry with me as I did on Jukka.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in CSS:

```
textarea {
    overflow:hidden;
    resize:none;
}
```

This will turn off the possibility of resizing the textarea and hides everything except the number of rows specified.

Additionally you may wish to restrict the amount of characters for the textarea via `maxlength` ([Spec](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)) which is possible since HTML5.

Comment: This does not prevent the user from entering any number of lines. It just prevents him from seeing all he has typed and from using a scrollbar.

Comment: No of the suggested solutions does prevent the user from typing more text than he's allowed to since they're client-side. The best attempt will be a combination of `overflow:hidden;`, `resize:none;`, `maxlength` and a server-side check.

Comment: The point is that these CSS settings do not impose a restriction on the number of lines even in the client-side sense; they only affect what input is visible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set such restrictions in CSS. You can set a maximum number of characters in HTML, but that’s not the same thing. You can use JavaScript that counts the lines and imposes restrictictions.

Normally, the best approach would seem to be to avoid the problem: instead of a `textarea` element, use four `input` elements. The downside is that the user needs to tab to the next field instead of just pressing Enter.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `maxlength` attribute could be used, but HTML, CSS, and JavaScript can be hacked. Do a Sever side check to be sure. Client side should also be used, but won't prevent a potential issue.